# IIS 7.5 Limit folder access to local users

Tags: iis-7.5

Is there any way I can limit a folder (and everything recursively down) in my webroot to local access only (i.e. requests from 127.0.0.1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the role service "IP and Domain Restrictions" to your server first.

Once that is installed:

1. Go into  IIS manager, and choose the folder you want to add the restriction to
2. Double click "IP Address and Domain Restrictions"
3. Click the "Add Allow Entry" action, and add the entry for 127.0.0.1
4. Click "Edit Feature Settings" and change the "Access for Unspecified clients" to be denied

That should do it for you.